# org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.bson.BsonDecimal128

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class org.bson.BsonDecimal128.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63)
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ChildCodecRegistry.get(ChildCodecRegistry.java:51)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.writeValue(BsonDocumentCodec.java:132)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:112)
    at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.encode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandMessage.writeTheWrites(InsertCommandMessage.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseWriteCommandMessage.encodeMessageBodyWithMetadata(BaseWriteCommandMessage.java:129)
    at com.mongodb.connection.RequestMessage.encodeWithMetadata(RequestMessage.java:160)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.sendMessage(WriteCommandProtocol.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.connection.WriteCommandProtocol.execute(WriteCommandProtocol.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:67)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InsertCommandProtocol.execute(InsertCommandProtocol.java:37)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.insertCommand(DefaultServerConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$2.executeWriteCommandProtocol(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:455)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run$RunExecutor.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:646)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$Run.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:401)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:179)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation$1.call(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:168)
    at com.mongodb.operation.MixedBulkWriteOperation.execute(MixedBulkWriteOperation.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:781)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:764)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertMany(MongoCollectionImpl.java:323)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.insertMany(MongoCollectionImpl.java:311)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MongoSpark.scala:119)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MongoSpark.scala:119)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:119)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:118)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:186)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withCollectionDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:184)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector$$anonfun$withDatabaseDo$1.apply(MongoConnector.scala:171)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withMongoClientDo(MongoConnector.scala:154)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withDatabaseDo(MongoConnector.scala:171)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoConnector.withCollectionDo(MongoConnector.scala:184)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:118)
    at com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark$$anonfun$save$1.apply(MongoSpark.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: No user can tell you much if you just share the stack of the exception. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: did you find the sollution for this?